# Real time low pass filter in C

Tags: c++, c, filter

I'm trying to implement an embedded design.
I receive u32 data from my board and want to add a LPF to the signal. Since I'm not very familiar with C code, I'm stuck right now. I followed a tutorial to get the basics about fixed point FIR, which works with static data.

Right now I take a sample from the input device and process the sample separately. There are some casts from u32 to int32_t, but I'm not really sure what's going on there.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

```
#define FILTER_LEN_LP 44
int16_t coeffsLPF[ FILTER_LEN_LP ] =
{
    87, 76, 106, 143, 185, 234, 289, 349,
    414, 483, 555, 628, 701, 773, 842, 907,
    966, 1017, 1060, 1093, 1115, 1126, 1126,
    1115, 1093, 1060, 1017, 966, 907, 842, 773,
    701, 628, 555, 483, 414, 349, 289, 234, 185,
    143, 106, 76, 87
};

void low_pass_filter(){
    u32 in_left;

    int k = 0;
    int filter_length = FILTER_LEN_LP;
    u32 acc; // accumulator for MACs
    u32 *coeffp; // pointer to coefficients

    u32 out_left;

    while (!XUartPs_IsReceiveData(UART_BASEADDR)) {

        in_left = Xil_In32(I2S_DATA_RX_L_REG);

        xil_printf("%d\n\r", in_left);

        out_left = 1 << 29;
        for ( k = 0; k < filter_length; k++ )
        {
            out_left += (int32_t)*coeffp++ * in_left;
        }

        // saturate the result
        if ( out_left > 0x3fffffff )
        {
           out_left = 0x3fffffff;
        } else if ( out_left < -0x40000000 ){
           out_left = -0x40000000;
        }

       xil_printf("%d\n\r", out_left);

        //in_right = Xil_In32(I2S_DATA_RX_R_REG);

        Xil_Out32(I2S_DATA_TX_L_REG, out_left);


        //Xil_Out32(I2S_DATA_TX_R_REG, in_right);

    }
    // break
    if(XUartPs_ReadReg(UART_BASEADDR, XUARTPS_FIFO_OFFSET) == 'q') menu();
    else low_pass_filter();
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem, specifically?

Comment: The signal isn't really filtered. I get lots of noise. But I don't know where to look first.. My knowledge of C is very limited.

Comment: @Barto I would seriously recommend you to compile your code with all warnings on, and take care of each single one.

Answer (score 1):

Your coefficients pointer has not been initialized before you read from it, leading to undefined behaviour. In this case it seems your program is reading random data for the coefficients, but it could do **anything**.

You need to reset the pointer before the start of the inner loop. For example:

```
void low_pass_filter(){
    // ...
    u32 *coeffp; // pointer to coefficients
    // ...
    while (!XUartPs_IsReceiveData(UART_BASEADDR)) {
        // ...
        coeffp = coeffsLPF; // reset to coeffsLPF so that each sample input is multiplied by all of the coefficients 
        for ( k = 0; k < filter_length; k++ )
        {
            // ...
```